# Using Alamofire and SwiftyJSON and it returns me null when I use json["email"]?

Tags: ios, alamofire, swifty-json

I imported both Alamofire and SwiftyJSON (latest versions) and I just want to try out the API calls.

here is what I am doing in viewDidLoad:

```
 url: String = "https://api.solvap.com" //this is not the real url of the api

 Alamofire.request(url, method: .get)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            let json = JSON(value)
            //this print statement prints the whole JSON list
            print(json)
            //this print statement just return null for some weird reason
            print(json["name"])
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Console output in Xcode:

```
 [
   {
     "name" : "John",
     "surname" : "Doe",
     "password" : "54321",
     "job" : "Developer",
     "token" : "iw4lcsk7h8do3y6fuw5vvzefn"
   }
]
null
```

Any thoughts how to fix this and why this happens?

Comment: The parsed JSON object is an array of dictionaries. Try printing `print(json.first?["name"])`

Comment: @vfn  I got error from the `print(json.first?["name"])`
Type 'JSON._Element' (aka '(String, JSON)') has no subscript members

Comment: Here is the Solution:

    `Alamofire.request(url, method: .get)
            .validate()
            .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                //removed the value from the case .success(let value):
                let json = JSON(data: response.data!)
                if let name = json[0]["name"].string {
                    //Now you got your value
                    print(name)
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }`

Comment: I used response.data to parse the data and then `let name = jason[0]["name"].string` so I could use this!

Comment: @PavlosNicolaou I would add some kind of verification in case the json comes empty. Something like "if (json.count > 0){ //do stuff }". If for any reason the json comes empty, your app will crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out.. If the API response looks like this:

```
(
    {
        "name" : "John",
        "surname" : "Doe",
        "password" : "54321",
        "job" : "Developer",
        "token" : "iw4lcsk7h8do3y6fuw5vvzefn"
    }
)
```

That means the API response is wrong and the perfect way is to fix the response from the Back-End and not trying to parse data from a wrong API response.

There is no reason to waste time on trying to parse data from a wrong API response.

The correct response of the API should look like this:

```
{
    "name" : "John",
    "surname" : "Doe",
    "password" : "54321",
    "job" : "Developer",
    "token" : "iw4lcsk7h8do3y6fuw5vvzefn"
}
```